# Angular ui.router renders home state, but not other states

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an app using the MEAN stack, and in my `index.ejs` files I have

`<div ui-view style="height: 100%"></div>`.

My `angularApp.js` file has the following states declared:

```
var app = angular.module('foundry-io', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'javascripts/views/main.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .state('print', {
      url: '/print',
      templateURL: 'javascripts/views/print.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}]);
```

I also have a navbar as follows:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
        <li class="hidden">
            <a href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" ui-sref="print">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#technology">Technology</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

The home state renders as expected, but when clicking the "Services" nav button the view that's rendered is a blank, black screen. How do I make additional views render beyond the "home" view?

Thank you.

Comment: any console error?

Comment: The error is: `jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /print`

Comment: Seem like your problem related to [this github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1423)